# OmniORB compilation fatal error Windows 10

Tags: omniorb

I'm trying to test OmbiORB V4.2.3 on a Virtual machine running Windows 10 pro 64bit. I have install all the necessary software (python 3.6.5, cygwin, VS 2017).

**configuration**

I have uncommented the following line in config.mk `platform = x86_win32_vs_15`. Added the following line to mk\platforms\[platform].mk `PYTHON = /cygdrive/c/Software/Python/Python36`.

**console**

Started the command promt with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64` and moved to the src directory. Added both Cygwin and Python to PATH with `set path=%path%;c:\Software\cygwin64\bin;c:\Software\Python`. When I did `make export` I see 2 things that might be the issue.

```
C:\Users\[user]\Documents\omniORB-4.2.3\src>make export
making export in src/tool...
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/[user]/Documents/omniORB-4.2.3/src/tool'
making export in src/tool/omniidl...
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/[user]/Documents/omniORB-4.2.3/src/tool/omniidl'
make[2]: /cygdrive/c/Software/Python/Python36: Command not found
making export in src/tool/omniidl/cxx...
make[3]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/[user]/Documents/omniORB-4.2.3/src/tool/omniidl/cxx'
make[3]: /cygdrive/c/Software/Python/Python36: Command not found
make[3]: /cygdrive/c/Software/Python/Python36: Command not found
make[3]: /cygdrive/c/Software/Python/Python36: Command not found
make[3]: /cygdrive/c/Software/Python/Python36: Command not found
../../../../bin/x86_win32/omkdepend -D__cplusplus -D_MSC_VER -I -DPYTHON_INCLUDE=<Python.h> -DPYTHON_THREAD_INC=<pythread.h> -DIDLMODULE_VERSION="0x2630" -DMSDOS -DOMNIIDL_EXECUTABLE -I. -I. -I../../../../include -D__WIN32__ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__x86__ -D__NT__ -D__OSVERSION__=4 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1 idlc.cc idlpython.cc idlfixed.cc idlconfig.cc idldump.cc idlvalidate.cc idlast.cc idlexpr.cc idlscope.cc idlrepoId.cc idltype.cc idlutil.cc idlerr.cc lex.yy.cc y.tab.cc
C:\Users\[user]\Documents\omniORB-4.2.3\bin\x86_win32\omkdepend.exe: warning:  idlpython.cc, line 57: incomplete include == "#  include PYTHON_INCLUDE"
```

and

```
idlpython.cc(31): error C2006: '#include': expected a filename, found 'identifier'
idlpython.cc(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '': No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [../../../../mk/win32.mk:490: idlpython.o] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/[user]/Documents/omniORB-4.2.3/src/tool/omniidl/cxx'
make[2]: *** [dir.mk:16: export] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/[user]/Documents/omniORB-4.2.3/src/tool/omniidl'
make[1]: *** [dir.mk:22: export] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/[user]/Documents/omniORB-4.2.3/src/tool'
make: *** [dir.mk:26: export] Error 2
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue that I'm facing?

Answer (score 0):

I assume

```
PYTHON = /cygdrive/c/Software/Python/Python36
```

to be the problem here:

```
...
make[2]: /cygdrive/c/Software/Python/Python36: Command not found
...
```

This line should specify the python executable, and at least on my Python 2.7 setup the exe is just called `python.exe` without any version suffix.

So, this line probably really should be

```
PYTHON = /cygdrive/c/Software/Python/python
** or maybe
PYTHON = /cygdrive/c/Software/Python/Python36/python
```

Note also that my notes on our build script say that cygwin stuff is case sensitive.